# Data.List.Split's `chunksOf` with 0 Value

Tags: list, haskell

`Data.List.Split`'s `chunksOf` has the type:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> :t chunksOf
chunksOf :: Int -> [e] -> [[e]]
```

Simple example:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> chunksOf 2 [1,2,3,4]
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

When I pass in a value of `0`, it returns an infinite list of empty list's:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> take 5 $ chunksOf 0 [1]
[[],[],[],[],[]]
```

What's the reason for this behavior? What's the advantage/reason for not returning a `Maybe [[a]]`?

Comment: i would guess it was design decision (they didn't want to introduce Maybe). You could ask why `head []` gives an error instead of Nothing. But you will quickly find there is safe version of head which does exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is precisely one sensible way to produce chunks of size 0 from a list, so it does that. It's not that useful, but it's better to produce something reasonable and useless than to deal with `Maybe` or throw exceptions.

Comment: While I am generally a big fan of starting induction from 0 when it's sensible to do so, I'm not so sure about this case. Usually we have `concat . chunksOf n == id`, but not for 0. An exception might be preferrable here: an infinite list might lead a program to run forever or go out of memory, while an exception at least points to the bug. Using `Maybe` is an option, but it seems a bit overkill here.

Comment: @chi, you make good points, but the trend these days seems to be very much toward totality. I think 0-length chunks giving an infinite stream is more obvious than saturated subtraction for `Nat`!

Comment: `here is precisely one sensible way to produce chunks of size 0 from a list` - could you please explain why it's sensible? I don't disagree - just want to understand.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, if you're asked to empty a bathtub with a bucket, you can probably do it in a few minutes. If you're asked to perform the same task with a coffee cup, it will take you longer. If you're asked to do it with a teaspoon, it will take much longer. If you're asked to do it with a 0-volume measure, it will take forever.